# Geographic Calculations Across Layers

Tags: qgis, point, vector, calculate-values

I have a layer with thousands of points and a different layer with census tracts. I want to determine the average value of each point per census tract. I have tried merging the layers together but QGIs does not permit the merging of a vector layer with a point layer. Any ideas or workarounds to determining the average value of a point centralized in one layer per census tract which is a second layer?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me: Census tracts= polygons? So each tract contains several points? And each points contains - what? An attribute with a numerical value? And now you want to calculate what? The mean value of this attribute per census tract polygon? Thus: the mean of all the points in the same polygon? If you could post a screenshot with points, census tracts + attribute  table, it would be easier to understand. Sharing your data (at least a sample of it, even dummy data) would help even more.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the value is stored in the points? This would be a Spatial Join.

- Add both features to a project (and probably make sure they have the same CRS)
- Go to "Toolbox" → "vector general" → "Join attribute by location (summary)"
- Add your polygon layer as "input layer", your Point layer as "join layer"
- tick the "intersect" box
- Select the point value field in the "fields to summarize" line
- select "mean" in the "summaries to calculate" line
- run the tool

This should give you a field with the mean of all intersecting points in a newly created join layer (polygon layer).

edit: there is a tutorial on how to do it (and the reverse one-to-many join if you want to add the polygon information to the points instead) here: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html